# Update Numpy array based on conditions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array - 
short example -

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

I need to update the array such that -

1. I update the first 0 to 1
2. I update all the values after first 0 to 0

So, for the above array, output will look like -

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I was able to achieve this in 2 steps -

1. Create an array of first 0's index - 
   zero_index = ((origArray==0).argmax(axis=1) + 1) # + 1 to get (index+1) 1s
2. Create output using list comprehensions
   [[1]*a + [0]*(6-a) for a in zero_index]

But it is taking a lot of time for ~1Mil rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumsum` to count how many zeros we've seen in each row so far:

```
c = (x == 0).cumsum(axis=1)
```

Gives you:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]])
```

Note that the places containing `1` are mostly the places we need to set to `1`, but the second-to-last row has two `1`s because it ended with `1, 0`.  Fix that with a second `cumsum`!

```
c = c.cumsum(axis=1)
```

Finally, use `np.select` to get the result:

```
np.select([c == 1, c > 1], [1, 0], 1)
```

Which gives the desired output:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Or, simpler but less flexible:

```
(c <= 1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Works faster. Thanks!